# Humanoid Rig Animations Not Playing Properly

Tags: unity, animation, blender, rigging

Although I have seen a few questions that are similar to my own, none had specific or clear answers that actually solved the problem, so here I am.

Just recently, I have imported a rig from Blender into Unity, along with a few embedded animations. As you can see here: https://gyazo.com/54f5717fa71170b198a77d5458aad919 the animations imported fine and function normally with the generic rig. The moment I switch the avatar to a humanoid-type rig, however, the only part that moves is the heart, as it is not mapped in the rig: https://gyazo.com/0f9a0b9a1c2580b848733e980fb9fcef.

As Unity has told me many times now, this is due to the humanoid rig's muscle system thing which doesn't make any sense.

So my question here is, how does one make an animation that works on humanoid rigs? Did I somehow import the Blender animation wrong or am I supposed to use Unity's animator to do it (even though *it* doesn't work either)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I have figured it out on my own. Since I was importing the animations via separate fbx files with embedded animations, not all of the animations came from humanoid rigs, so the animations wouldn't play properly.